Ignite Cache Event Listener handle duplicate for EVT_CACHE_EXPIRED
We are using Apache Ignite 2.16 configured as 3 Nodes as POD replica .
Our Application connects to the Ignite Cluster as Thick Client to add/retrieve entry in a
cache.
The Cache is is configured for ATOMIC & REPLICATED,   we have configured a Cache Event Listener for EVT_CACHE_EXPIRED event.
When a cache expire, we are able to see application gets events Listener called 3 times.
How do we handle listener so that i process only one of the event, and discard other event
What is the best practice to handle duplicate of events for same Cache Key in the listener

You're getting one event per copy of the data, which is the expected behaviour.
Typically, the best option is to use a continuous query.

We are using the Cache for a Use case. Sending a request to a Third party which has an API with Async Pattern, We send REquest and they send ACk and Later call our API as call back
We would like to trap Late Good Resposne or if they have not called, to resume our process, we use this cache , upon expiry - Using Listener we trigger remaining steps of ourprocess
Now due 3 nodes, Our process getting called 3 times. is there any option with Filter or anything to detect duplciate

@Karthik_Rajendiran I don't really have anything to add beyond what's in the answer. To be blunt, you're using the wrong API.
